# cron job firing but command is truncated after `\`

Tags: cron

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server which I am trying to automatically make sleep and wake each night and morning.

I have added the following command to a cron job which fires 5 minutes before midnight every day:

```
/usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -l -t $(date +\%s -d 'tomorrow 07:20')
```

(I'm doing it thusly because I would like the job to be easily understandable -- using seconds -- which had worked -- is not as easily understandable.)

It "runs" but fails.  Syslog reports what command `cron` tried running:

```
/usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -l -t $(date +\
```

In other words `cron` seems to be truncating this part:

```
%s -d 'tomorrow 07:20')
```

I should mention that when I execute the full command in a terminal window it immediately puts the computer to sleep (and it wakes properly the following morning, too).  It only has a problem when running as a `cron` job.

Comment: What as the actual line you added in crontab? Also, which crontab file did you edit?

Comment: @galoget please don't add version tags like [tag:16.04] unless the question is version-specific. A question simply mentioning a version doesn't make it version specific.

Comment: So the question really is why the backslash is being treated literally rather than as an escape for the `%`? the obvious thing to check is that it really is an ASCII `\\` (not a unicode character - that can happen sometimes if text is copypasted from a browser for example)

Comment: @muru : the actual line I added was exactly as presented:
    /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -l -t $(date +\%s -d 'tomorrow 07:20')

I used Webmin to add it to crontab.  It is neither in /etc/cron.d nor /etc/cron.daily . . . but it does *attempt* to run (daily) -- are you sure the location is important?

If I
    crontab -u root -l
it shows the job (interestingly no other root jobs) exactly as I entered it.

There was a downvoted answer here which has now been deleted.  It suggested putting double quotes around the +\%s portion of the date command.  I tried that and it had no effect.

Comment: @muru: I see that webmin has put the command into /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root   This seems to be the correct place to put a user-generated crontab with root permissions

Comment: @steeldriver: good idea!  Unfortunately, that wasn't it.  I re-keyed the whole thing and it still truncates at the `\`

Comment: @FBachofner well, the syntax of the cron files changes with the location. `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d` need a username before the command, `/etc/cron.{daily,weekly...}` are actually executable files, directly run by cron, not cronjob specifications, user crontabs (`crontab -e`) don't need user specification, etc. So yes, the location may matter. How did you "rekey" it by the way? Using `sudo crontab -e` or still using webmin?

Comment: @muru:  I had used Webmin again.  Using sudo crontab -e shows the command having TWO '\' before the '%s'  INTERESTING.  This is almost certainly it.  I removed one and will retest.  Webmin now shows the command without any '\' -- looks like a bug in Webmin, as /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root shows the command correctly.  I'll report back.  BTW, why when editing with sudo crontab -e, Nano reports the file at /tmp/crontab.S9yQAf/crontab . . . but then ultimately writes to the correct location.  This seems odd to me.  Looks like I need to read up on how this method of crontab editing works . . .

Comment: @FBachofner that's standard behaviour for crontab. It gives you a temporary file to edit and then copies it to the actual location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cron command was entered using wemin

webmin takes care of special characters in cron commands, you can enter them as on the command line, no need to escape them like you must do when editing crontab directly.

in this case the cron special character % is masked automatically as \%.
you entered \% in webmin whitch is then masked as \\%.

/usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -l -t $(date +%s -d 'tomorrow 07:20')

should work in webmin and command line

BTW: \% on command line is the same as %, this why your command is working in both versions on command line